# SwiftUI call function on variable change

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I am trying to convert a view of my watchOS App to Swift UI. 
I wanted to port the volume control that can be found in watchKit to SwiftUI with custom controls. In the image below you can see the current state of the view.

The volume control changes the progress of the ring according to current state `volume` and the `volume` also changes when I turn the Digital Crown. 
Without SwiftUI it was possible to call a function on the turn of the crown. This has changed and the system only allows me to bind a variable to it.

What I want to do know is to bind a variable and call a function on every change of that variable. Because the normal Digital Crown behavior does not fulfill my needs.

One thing that works, but is far from perfect is:

```swift
.digitalCrownRotation($crownAccumulator, from: -100.0, through: 100.0, by: 1, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: true, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
.onReceive(Just(self.crownAccumulator), perform: self.crownChanged(crownAccumulator:))
```

OnReceive will be called with every twist of the crown, but it will also be called with every other update to the view.

So what I want is a pipeline like this:

Crown rotates → `crownAccumulator` changes → Function called async → Function updates `volume`

In the past I would have done this with a didSet, but this is no longer available

Here the code of it:

```swift
    @ObservedObject var group: Group
    @State var animateSongTitle: Bool = false

    @State var songTitle: String = "Very long song title that should be scrolled"
    @State var artist: String = "Artist name"


    @State var volume: Int = 30
    @State var isMuted = false
    @State var crownAccumulator: CGFloat = 0.0


    var body: some View {

       VStack(alignment: .center) {
            TitleView(songTitle: $songTitle, artist: $artist)
            GroupControlButtons(
                skipPreviousAction: skipPrevious,
                skipNextAction: skipNext,
                playPauseAction: playPause,
                group: group)

            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    VolumeControl(
                        volumeLevel: $volume,
                        isMuted: $isMuted,
                        muteAction: self.muteButtonPressed)
                            .frame(minWidth: 40.0, idealWidth: 55, minHeight: 40.0, idealHeight: 55, alignment: .center)
                            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)


                }
            }


        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom])
        .focusable(true)
//        .digitalCrownRotation($crownAccumulator)
        .digitalCrownRotation($crownAccumulator, from: -100.0, through: 100.0, by: 1, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: true, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
        .onReceive(Just(self.crownAccumulator), perform: self.crownChanged(crownAccumulator:))
```

Here's the current view: 
 
[image: Current View]

Comment: How you solved "@State var songTitle: String = "Very long song title that should be scrolled" I have same problem my text don't fit

Answer (score 18):

You can use a custom `Binding`, that calls some code in `set`. For example from :

```swift
extension Binding {
    /// Execute block when value is changed.
    ///
    /// Example:
    ///
    ///     Slider(value: $amount.didSet { print($0) }, in: 0...10)
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                self.wrappedValue = $0
                execute($0)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand this 'hack'. The principle of SwiftUI is to automatically react to binding changes, so why add some extra code? You set a value on a '@Published' property, and all the views are redrawn. If you use combine only, all observers are notified and then you do what's needed at the right place. $property.sink { // do this or that  }.

Answer (score 6):

As you said "**In the past I would have done this with a didSet, but this is no longer available**" I test below code it works perfectly

```
struct pHome: View {
 @State var prog:Int = 2 {
    willSet{
        print("willSet: newValue =\(newValue)  oldValue =\(prog)") 
    }
    didSet{
        print("didSet: oldValue=\(oldValue) newValue=\(prog)")
        //Write code, function do what ever you want todo 
    }
} 
 var body: some View {
VStack{
                Button("Update"){
                    self.prog += 1
                }
                Text("\(self.prog)%")
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: True! It works for state variables. 
On the volume control I have a binding with `$volume` and didSet does not work on bindings as far as I see it.

Comment: use current object reference to access directly @State var instead ** bindings**. pass **self** as parameter

Comment: didSet does not execute for me. The State variable is passed to a separate View where it is bound. didSet in the parent View is apparently not called in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but you could use `.onChange` instead of `.onReceive`, it would then only be called when value changes.

However, neither `.onChange` or `.onReceive` are needed here

This is slightly different subject, but there is too much `@State` variables in this view. ( I guess there were, since it is a relatively old question )

Don't forget **@State declares a new source of truth for the view**,
therefore it should be used with parcimony ( like for a display mode, a filter, or any property concerning only the view ). In this case, as in many cases, the source of truth is outside..

So by simply binding the view to the model, the cycle `User action -> value update -> view update` is done naturally.

Then, in the didSet of your player `crownAccumulator` property, you do the change on the model you need to do, and the view will update automatically accordingly to the new change.

Note that you may need to show other views in your app, but still be able to change volume with the crown. So I suggest to also move the crown accumulator into the player state.

**View Side**

```swift
// The current tune information, provided by model ( Song name, artist, duration..) - Could also be in the PlayerState, since there is only one player and one tune playing in the whole application
@ObservedObject var currentTune: TuneInfo

// The global player state ( Volume, isMuted, isPaused.. )
@EnvironmentObject var playerState: PlayerState

var body: View {
   VStack {
      ...
   }
   .digitalCrownRotation($playerState.crownAccumulator, from: -100.0, through: 100.0, by: 1, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: true, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
}
```

**Model/Controller side:**

```swift
struct PlayerState {
    // Published values that will retrigger view rendering when changed
    @Published var isMuted = false
    @Published var volume: Int = 30

    var crownAccumulator: CGFloat {
       didSet { volume = volumeForCrownValue() }
    }

    private func volumeForCrownValue() -> Int {
         // Your formula to compute volume
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. This solution is the one I chose in the most recent version as it is the most elegant. onChange is relatively new (watchOS 7+), but I saw some code that ports it back to older versions