# SwiftUI toggle() function on Published values stopped triggering didSet with Swift 5.2

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, swift5, xcode11.4

I have just updated my Xcode to 11.4 from 11.3 and my project written in SwiftUI started to behave differently. I used to call `toggle()` function for boolean values and it used to trigger `didSet` property observer, however, it is not working any more.

Let' say we have a `State` property called `isSettingOn`. I used to call this:

`isSettingOn.toggle()`

which was triggering `didSet` observer of the property. Now, only if I call this:

`isSettingOn = true`

it is working.

My projects are all based on this behaviour and now this change basically broke everything. Does anyone know if I am actually doing anything wrong here?

**Edit:**

Demo code added:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isSettingOn: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            print("didSet isSettingOn")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isSettingOn = true // will trigger didSet
            self.isSettingOn.toggle() // won't trigger didSet
        }) {
            Text("Toggle isSettingOn")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine here. Would you provide demo code?

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, I have updated my question with the sample code. Also, I have realised that the first issue (view not being updated) was related to the second issue I mentioned (didSet not being triggered) hence I also updated the question content.

Comment: try this, it works!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59391476/8457280

Comment: Looks like a bug that will be fixed in next Swift release. See https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/29931

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I have posted an answer that this is fixed in Xcode 11.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `Xcode 11.4 and 11.4.1` and it was fixed in `Xcode 11.5 (Beta)` with `Swift 5.2.4`.