# Swiftui ObservableObject with array not update view

Tags: swiftui, observableobject, swiftui-scrollview

I have a problem with `Array` using `ObservableObject` in my view. I have an empty array. I call a function at page `onAppear`. When the data is returned, the view does not update with the new data in array:

```swift
class NewsState: ObservableObject {
    
    private let base: String = "api"
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    
    @Published var wagsList: Array<UserSlider> = [] {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    func getList() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "\(base)/UserApi/getList")
        var mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        AF.request(mutableURLRequest).responseData { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            let resp = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Array<UserSlider>.self, from: data)
            for i in resp {
                let userSlider = UserSlider(id: i.id, uid: i.uid, image: i.image)
                self.wagsList.append(userSlider)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my view I have this:

```swift
HStack {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            if(self.newsState.wagsList.count != 0) {
                ForEach(self.newsState.wagsList, id: \.self) { wags in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            URLImage(URL(string: "\(wags.image)")!, expireAfter: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)) { proxy in
                                proxy.image
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                    .overlay(
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                    )
                                    .contentShape(Circle())
                            }.frame(width: 62, height: 62)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("10K")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(Font.custom("Metropolis-Bold", size: 15))
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("followers")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(Font.custom("Metropolis-Normal", size: 15))
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //loader
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: initPage)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I see that the problem is caused by `ScrollView`.

Comment: Have you for e.g. printed out the array before and after the on appear? This would help to determine where the error might lay. It can be either in the getList or also in your View.

Comment: Why do you even use `ObservableObjectPublisher`? `Published` should already do that. Also, as you are using `willSet` here, just know that there's a bug related with those functions not calling on `Xcode 11.4 and 11.4.1`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907882/swiftui-toggle-function-on-published-values-stopped-triggering-didset-with-swi

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
class NewsState: ObservableObject {

    private let base: String = "api"

    @Published var wagsList: Array<UserSlider> = []

    func getList() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "\(base)/UserApi/getList")
        var mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        AF.request(mutableURLRequest).responseData { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            let resp = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Array<UserSlider>.self, from: data)

            let results = resp.map { UserSlider(id: $0.id, uid: $0.uid, image: $0.image) }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.wagsList = results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i move getList in the init of observable the list appear, 
I however need both on Apper

Comment: This sounds most likely like an Issue in your View. Might consider sharing the whole View? Do you have a @ObservedObject in front of your ```var newsState``` in view? Also give ForEach ids to differentiate like this: ```ForEach(self.newsState.wagsList, id: \.self)```

Comment: I edited the original question, I noticed that the problem is given by the scrollview, if I remove that they appear

Comment: I gave a fixed height at HStack inside ScrollView and now they appear

Answer (score 0):

As it is not clear to me where the error might lay. It could be either in `getList` or in your View.

This is an easy example of how it works with a `Published` and `ObserverdObject`:
Note: your getList function is not in this solution as the error could be with your API, JSON ect.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var state = NewsState()

    var body: some View {
        Group { //needed for the IF Statement below
            if state.stringList.count > 0 {
                ForEach(self.state.stringList, id: \.self){ s in
                    Text(String(s))
                }
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.state.getNewList()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


class NewsState: ObservableObject {

    @Published var stringList: Array<String> = []

    init() {
        self.getList()
    }

    func getList() {
        self.stringList.append("New")
    }

    func getNewList() {
        self.stringList = []
        self.stringList.append("New new")
    }
}
```